# npm install module -g Gives MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: node.js, npm, memory-leaks

Using:

- node 12.9.0
- npm 6.10.2
- macOS Mojave

Was following an online tutorial which was teaching beginners how to install npm modules globally by issuing the `-g` flag:

```sh
myapp$ npm i nodemon@1.19.1 -g
```

Output:

```sh
(node:26645) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:26645) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:26645) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:26645) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:26645) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:26645) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:26645) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:26645) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:26645) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:26645) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
/usr/local/bin/nodemon -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js

> fsevents@1.2.9 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
[fsevents] Success: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote

> nodemon@1.19.1 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

+ nodemon@1.19.1
added 289 packages from 144 contributors in 13.382s
```

Am a Node.js newbie so how can I fix / turn off this warning?

Do I have to use `Use emitter.setMaxListeners()` inside all of my node.js project files for which the modules needed are globally installed?

This is also the same warning when I do use sudo:

`sudo npm i nodemon@1.19.1 -g`

Answer (score 2):

I was just having this problem too. It's a bug which seems to be fixed in v12.9.1. Updating did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, the encountered issue stems from network-related changes. Over the past two days, there have been upgrades to the network infrastructure, leading to the unavailability of the official NPM image address at `https://registry.npmjs.org/` When executing `npm install`, a warning surfaces:

```bash
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket] Use emitter. setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

This warning is followed by an error after a certain duration:

```bash
Npm ERR! Code ETIMEOUT
Npm ERR! Errno ETIMEOUT
Npm ERR! Network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm Failed, reason:
Npm ERR! Network This is a problem related to network connectivity
Npm ERR! Network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings
Npm ERR! Network
Npm ERR! Network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
Npm ERR! Network 'proxy' config is set property See: 'npm help config'
```

To address this issue, consider switching to an alternate image source within Mainland China, such as:

```bash
Npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org // Taobao
Npm config set registry https://mirrors.huaweicloud.com/repository/npm // Huawei
```

For reference only.